# Actionbar sherlock light theme

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

Now I am working on a android app using actionbar sherlock and fragment.I used the following theme.

```
<style name="Theme.AndroidDevelopers" parent="Theme.Sherlock.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>

    </style>
```

And I got the following Output.[image]

But I want use the light theme so I changed the parent as

```
parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow"
```

Then I got the following output[image]

The light theme is missing the blue underline. How can i make that blue underline?...Please help me friends.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create you own theme in order to do that:

```
<resources>
  <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
  </style>

  <style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

As the Background you can then put a modified 9 patch Image with a blue underline. Look at your Android Sdk > API 13+ there should be the original Actionbar bavkground drawables. Just modify them and set it as background. Don't forget to set this Theme as your App theme later on.

Edit:

Here are some 9 Patch images from Jake Whartons Action Bar Sherlock(what a coincidence that he formated my post earlier...:) ):

[image: blue Stroke]
[image: grey background]

Answer (score 2):

Create your own style for action bar and override `background` property:

```
<style name="MyActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_action_bar</item>
    <item name="background">@drawable/bg_action_bar</item>
</style>
```

Use this style for your action bar in theme:

```
<style name="Theme.AndroidDevelopers" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.ForceOverflow">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarStyle</item>
</style>
```

Take a look onto `res\drawable-hdpi\abs__ab_transparent_light_holo.9.png` drawable inside `ActionBarSherlock` sources how to create 9-patch drawable with color strip line at the bottom.